# Как заменить ToolBar на другой? В зависимости от фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Как заменить layout тулбара на другой, в зависимости от фрагмента? В некоторых фрагментах нужен тулбар c TabLayout, причем табы должны быть частью тулбара, чтобы градиент смотрелся красиво. В других фрагментах нужен большой тулбар, который занимает 50% экрана и содержит большую TextView с названием приложения. Во всех остальных - обычный тулбар, который ведет себя как actionBar.
Я пробовал подключить свой тулбар так (предварительно разметил тулбар в XML фрагмента):

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

Результат видно внизу. Почему-то они настакиваются друг на друга.
[image: Result of adding another toolbar]

Так как же следует кастомизировать тулбар? Вот несколько картинок, сделанных на коленке в пейнте, которые, тем не менее, должны дать представление чего я хочу добиться.

[image: One fragment]
[image: Another fragment]
[image: basic fragment]

Любая помощь приветствуется! Возможно, тут ошибка в самой архитектуре приложения и я что-то изначально не так делал? Если нужно - представлю xml и любой другой код.

Comment: TollBar  != ToolBar

Comment: спасибо, не заметил сразу

Comment: Скриншоты слишком крупные, на FullHD мониторе смотреть неудобно

Comment: Вам не надо устанавливать тулбар в хост-активити фрагментов. Устанавливайте его в разметке каждого фрагмента, какой нужен и все.

Comment: @pavlofff если не ставить его в хост-активити, то тогда будет довольно проблематично обработать нажатие на кнопку назад и подключить библиотеку для анимации стрелочки, когда NavigationDrawer открывается (когда открыта боковая шторка - появляется стрелка, иначе - меню)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте следующее решение:

1) создаёте для **ActionBar-a** создаёте *layout*, которым впоследствии будете манипулировать:

```
your_name.xml:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/custom_action_bar_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/custom_action_bar_tab"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="48dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2) В *activity* для последующей манипуляции заводите поле с типом View (по своему усмотрению). После добавляете его к **Toolar**-y:

```
private View viewContent;

...
viewContent = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_name, null);
((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
myToolbar.addView(viewContent);
```

3) Сами реализуете методы которые будут скрывать/показывать нужные view (custom_action_bar_main и custom_action_bar_tab),  устанавливать им высоту и т.д.

**Update**:

Можно немного элегантнее правильнее сделать:

заменить:

```
    viewContent = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_name, null);
```

на:

```
    viewContent = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_name, myToolbar);
```

и удалить строчку:

```
    myToolbar.addView(viewContent);
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что для каждого фрагмента - свой отдельный layout для toolbar'a? Хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: нет стойте, layout один. нужно в activity создать методы которые им манипулируют

Comment: То есть, все же, один layout? Тогда я не очень понимаю, как добавлять или удалять из него элементы, в зависимости от фрагмента.

Comment: "скрывать/показывать нужные view "

Comment: т.е. вызывать у них метод setVisibility() с параметрами GONE или VISIBLE. И выставлять нужную высоту через соотвествующий LayoutParams