# Разный Toolbar для фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment, toolbar

Вот есть у меня одно активити и к нему 2 фрагмента. Как сделать так чтоб у них отображались разные ToolBar. Вот для одного с текстом ввода, а в другом пустой toolbar

Использую `Navigation Drawer Activity`. 
Вот мой AppBarLayout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Использую панель инструментов
Фрагмент

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return view;
}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_test, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

menu->fragment_test.xml

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/frag1_item"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:title="lol"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

[image: Вот результат использование]

На другом фрагменте

[image: Без инструментов]

Comment: Можно попробовать этим способом [кастомный toolbar](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html#making-the-action-bar-dynamic)

Comment: а есть ли способ чтоб подменивать toolbar? А не редактировать существующий

Comment: Возможные дубликаты: [Как заменить ToolBar на другой? В зависимости от фрагмента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451305/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-toolbar-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%92-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/451350), [Свой toolbar для каждого Fragment'a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517118/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-toolbar-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-fragmenta)

Comment: @Ewrei_228 Устанавливайте нужный вам Toolbar в разметке каждого фрагмента, а не один на всех в Activity

Comment: @pavlofff, хороший вариант. А с точки программирование это правильно? Если будет 20-30 фрагментов, а из них надо только 1-2 ToolBar менять

Comment: @Ewrei_228 если у вас планируется более 20 фрагментов в приложении, то с большой долей вероятности можно сказать, что вы делаете что то не так, трудно представить приложение с более 20 уникальных интерфейсов

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как заменить ToolBar на другой? В зависимости от фрагмента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451305/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-toolbar-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%92-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)